# Get Contend-ID(cid) of inline image in incoming email using sendgrid and c#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I need to replace inline images' `src` by the azure blob url where all the attachments are stored, but I am not able to get Contennt-ID(cid) of the inline images, but when I check original message in gmail I get the Contend-ID

```
--94eb2c18fcdc41670405404c850c--
--94eb2c18fcdc41670805404c850d
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="IMG_20151020_195656.jpg"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="IMG_20151020_195656.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <ii_iv0m2msp0_15823f914fddab1e>
X-Attachment-Id: ii_iv0m2msp0_15823f914fddab1e
```